# understanding javascript functions and var

Tags: javascript

I just went through my class note and not really understood

```
var x = 1;
function func1() 
{
    x+= 10; 
}
func2 = function( x ) 
{ 
    x += 5;
}
```

what does the line  func2 = function( x )  means? does x will be 15?

Comment: Asked and answered. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: so many vote down I really searched and didnt find the answer.. thanks anyway but im still not sure if func2 will update x

Comment: func2 will not update the value of the global `var x` because x is a local variable of func2. Variables declared as arguments of a function are local variables. It may have the same identifier, but it points to a different object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass arguments that are primitives to functions they are passed by value. But if you pass in an argument that is an object it is passed by reference.

```
function myfunction(x)
{
    // x is equal to 4
    x = 5;
   // x is now equal to 5
}

var x = 4;
alert(x); // x is equal to 4

myfunction(x); 
alert(x); // x is still equal to 4

function myobject()
{
    this.value = 5;
}

var o = new myobject();
alert(o.value); // o.value = 5

function objectchanger(fnc)
{
    fnc.value = 6;
}

objectchanger(o);
alert(o.value); // o.value is now equal to 6
```